# How to delete a copy of a system font

Tags: mojave, font, sip

At some point I made copies of all the fonts in the System>Library folder. I would now like to delete those duplicates, which are not in use and are not in a System folder. But macOS (Mojave) won't let me because the copies inherited the protections of the originals. I'm not trying to change anything that's in the System folder itself. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this proved far easier than I expected. All I had to do was temporarily disable System Integrity Protection.

Comment: Where were the files saved?

Comment: To a folder inside my Home directory where I keep uninstalled fonts.

Comment: Weird. If I copy a font from /System/Library/Fonts to my Desktop, I can delete it straight away.